# how to enter ESC key during cucumberJS test run

Tags: angular, protractor, bdd, cucumberjs

The UI that i have automated has a dropdown. After the test goes through and clicks on the options I want the test to enter the ESC key so the dropdown closes.

Until the dropdown closes the other elements on the page are not visible. If I make it click on any other element it fails since the element is not clickable. The only way I see is to hit the ESC key so the dropdown closes but I'm having issues with it.

This is what I'm using: I have it in the Cucumber steps file:

```
return browser.actions().sendKeys(protractor.Key.ESC).perform();
```

I get an error saying "WebDriver Error:unknown error: keys should be a string".

Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Protractor 5.3.0 docs, the sendKeys command should be executed on a DOM element. http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebElement.prototype.sendKeys

For example: `return element(by.css('#myInput')).sendKeys(protractor.Key.ENTER);`